# Slicing in paraview

Tags: paraview

The `Slice` option in Paraview with selection `plane`, has a origin and normal to define the plane.

I am trying to export the slice data in `csv` format. However, the simulation domain is very large and therefore the slice also is quite large (which needs to be processed in `matlab` further). I need only the specific region of the slice. Is it possible to reduce the slice by creating a plane based on points by user or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only interested in a part of the slice, you can use the Clip filter on the volume to extract the region of interest and then slice this region.

1. select your volume
2. use the Clip filter
3. in the properties panel, set the *Clip Type* parameter as "Box"
4. set the dimensions of the box

   - in the GUI: move the circles of the Clip widget
   - in the Python Shell: `your_volume.ClipType.Bounds = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax]`, where *your_volume* in the volume proxy
5. check the *Inside Out* option, to keep only what is in the clip box
6. create your slice from the clip proxy

Comment: Your solution is very logical. But when I do `slice` and then `clip` with type `box`, I dont see the clipped plane itself. Any idea why is this so?

Comment: In this case you should first apply the Clip filter on the volume, and create the slice on the clipped volume. I edited my answer.

Comment: I am exporting the values from the plane. Due to scaling of the box, the slice plane contains edges, which are exactly not at the points values (meaning extrapolated values at the edges/hanging points). Is it possible to only export the point data and not the hanging points at the edges?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `Extract Cells By Region` instead of `Clip`. The two filters work similarly except `Extract Cells By Region` pulls out whole cells rather than cutting them up. It also supports the `box` region. Also, I highly recommend doing the `Slice` before the `Extract Cells By Region`. It will be much more space efficient and probably faster.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @KennethMoreland, I didn't think so much of the memory & speed issues. I suggested this solution to avoid the problem of the zero-thickness box that happens for both `Extract Cells By Region` and `Clip` filters. Do you think it is a bug ? (I'm on PV 4.3, it may have been fixed). It happens when the slice normal is parallel to X, Y or Z.

Comment: Yes, you are right @BertrandGazanion, there is still an issue with the box clip 3D widget when the data are in an axis-aligned plane as you describe (I just tried it with PV 5.1). Until that is fixed you can work around the issue by changing any 0 scale factors to some positive number. Or, you can do as you originally said and extract or clip first as long as the data are not too large. Sathish did originally say the data was large, so it might be better to work around the box bug in this case.